Permissions error when trying to get codebuild to push to ECR AWS because it's registering as an unknown user
As the title suggests, my codebuild is not letting me fulfill my buildscript to push the docker image to ECR. It works perfectly when on my local machine, but not in codebuild. The error message is like so:
denied: User: arn:aws:iam::311791021927:user/ServerlessAccount is not authorized to perform: ecr:InitiateLayerUpload on resource: arn:aws:ecr:***:014498627014:repository/squared-www because no resource-based policy allows the ecr:InitiateLayerUpload action

The issue is, user 311791021927 doesn't actually exist in my IAM or anywhere, this is my buildspec.yml:
version: 0.2

env:
  secrets-manager:
    DOMAIN: "squared-envs:DOMAIN"
    EMAIL_USERNAME: "squared-envs:EMAIL_USERNAME"
    EMAIL_PASSWORD: "squared-envs:EMAIL_PASSWORD"
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: "squared-envs:AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: "squared-envs:AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"
    AWS_S3_BUCKET: "squared-envs:AWS_S3_BUCKET"
    AWE_REGION: "squared-envs:AWE_REGION"
    CLIENT_ID: "squared-envs:CLIENT_ID"
    HOOKDECK_AUTH_TOKEN: "squared-envs:HOOKDECK_AUTH_TOKEN"
    JWT_SECRECT: "squared-envs:JWT_SECRECT"
    KINDE_CLIENT_ID: "squared-envs:KINDE_CLIENT_ID"
    KINDE_CLIENT_SECRET: "squared-envs:KINDE_CLIENT_SECRET"
    KINDE_ISSUER_URL: "squared-envs:KINDE_ISSUER_URL"
    KINDE_POST_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL: "squared-envs:KINDE_POST_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL"
    KINDE_POST_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL: "squared-envs:KINDE_POST_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL"
    KINDE_SITE_URL: "squared-envs:KINDE_SITE_URL"
    MONGO_URL: "squared-envs:MONGO_URL"
    NEXTAUTH_SECRET: "squared-envs:NEXTAUTH_SECRET"
    NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID: "squared-envs:NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID"
    NEXT_PUBLIC_CONFIRM_URL: "squared-envs:NEXT_PUBLIC_CONFIRM_URL"
    NEXT_PUBLIC_GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET: "squared-envs:NEXT_PUBLIC_GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET"
    NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER: "squared-envs:NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER"
    NEXT_PUBLIC_URL: "squared-envs:NEXT_PUBLIC_URL"
    NODE_ENV: "squared-envs:NODE_ENV"
    PORT: "squared-envs:PORT"
    SEED_PASSWORD: "squared-envs:SEED_PASSWORD"
    GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID: "squared-envs:GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"
    GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET: "squared-envs:GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"
    GITHUB_CLIENT_ID: "squared-envs:GITHUB_CLIENT_ID"
    GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET: "squared-envs:GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET"

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - aws ecr get-login-password --region $ECR_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $ECR_REGISTRY_URI
      - echo Creating .env file...
      - echo "DOMAIN=$DOMAIN" >> .env
      - echo "EMAIL_USERNAME=$EMAIL_USERNAME" >> .env
      - echo "EMAIL_PASSWORD=$EMAIL_PASSWORD" >> .env
      - echo "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" >> .env
      - echo "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" >> .env
      - echo "AWS_S3_BUCKET=$AWS_S3_BUCKET" >> .env
      - echo "AWE_REGION=$AWE_REGION" >> .env
      - echo "CLIENT_ID=$CLIENT_ID" >> .env
      - echo "HOOKDECK_AUTH_TOKEN=$HOOKDECK_AUTH_TOKEN" >> .env
      - echo "JWT_SECRECT=$JWT_SECRECT" >> .env
      - echo "KINDE_CLIENT_ID=$KINDE_CLIENT_ID" >> .env
      - echo "KINDE_CLIENT_SECRET=$KINDE_CLIENT_SECRET" >> .env
      - echo "KINDE_ISSUER_URL=$KINDE_ISSUER_URL" >> .env
      - echo "KINDE_POST_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL=$KINDE_POST_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL" >> .env
      - echo "KINDE_POST_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL=$KINDE_POST_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL" >> .env
      - echo "KINDE_SITE_URL=$KINDE_SITE_URL" >> .env
      - echo "MONGO_URL=$MONGO_URL" >> .env
      - echo "NEXTAUTH_SECRET=$NEXTAUTH_SECRET" >> .env
      - echo "NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID=$NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID" >> .env
      - echo "NEXT_PUBLIC_CONFIRM_URL=$NEXT_PUBLIC_CONFIRM_URL" >> .env
      - echo "NEXT_PUBLIC_GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET=$NEXT_PUBLIC_GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET" >> .env
      - echo "NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER=$NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER" >> .env
      - echo "NEXT_PUBLIC_URL=$NEXT_PUBLIC_URL" >> .env
      - echo "NODE_ENV=$NODE_ENV" >> .env
      - echo "PORT=$PORT" >> .env
      - echo "SEED_PASSWORD=$SEED_PASSWORD" >> .env
      - echo Building Docker images...
      - DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker-compose build --progress=plain

  build:
    commands:
      - echo Tagging Docker images...
      - docker tag squared-www:latest $ECR_REGISTRY_URI/squared-www:latest
      - docker tag squared-web:latest $ECR_REGISTRY_URI/squared-web:latest
      - docker tag squared-api:latest $ECR_REGISTRY_URI/squared-api:latest
      - docker tag squared-nginx:latest $ECR_REGISTRY_URI/squared-nginx:latest

  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Pushing Docker images to Amazon ECR...
      - docker push $ECR_REGISTRY_URI/squared-www:latest
      - docker push $ECR_REGISTRY_URI/squared-web:latest
      - docker push $ECR_REGISTRY_URI/squared-api:latest
      - docker push $ECR_REGISTRY_URI/squared-nginx:latest

artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'

cache:
  paths:
    - '/var/lib/docker'
    - '/root/.cache/buildkit'

From the server logs, I can see that all of the environment issues are being set correctly so that's not a potential issue. So what I can't figure out is, what's causing the user to exist? And why can't I edit it's permissions in IAM (because it doesn't exist).

I'm pretty sure 311791021927 is your AWS account ID, and ServerlessAccount is the name of the IAM user account.

311791021927 isn't my id, my id is 0144**********, and I don't have a user named ServerlessAccount

Well that part of the ARN is the AWS account ID, not a user ID. So you need to look at your CodeBuild environment to figure out where that is coming from. You might try adding some commands to your build, like aws sts get-caller-identity to see what the AWS CLI is using for AWS credentials.

Turns out the issue was that a while ago in this project someone implemented an s3 bucket and used AWS ACCESS IDs as environment variables. These were overwriting my access keys and causing it to login under the wrong account.
